# Подойдет ли svg формат для картинок?

Tags: java, android

Я хочу попробовать закачать в папку drawable, картинки нарисованные в *svg* формате. Есть библиотеки, которые работают с этим форматом. Подойдет ли он для вывода изображений на разных устройствах так, чтобы не пришлось под каждую плотность экрана создавать папку с набором изображений?

Answer (score 3):

SVG - масштабируемая векторная графика, соответственно, качество изображения будет одинаково отличным хоть на 3.5" 320×480 экране смартфона, хоть на 50" 4K TV. Если у Вас есть все требуемые картинки и они подходят по всем требованиям - смело используйте.

Вот, кстати, неплохая статья на хабре https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/twins/blog/166093/